# Truncated Logcat Exception Message

Tags: android, firebase, logcat, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to debug an android app error (in AS2.1beta3) but the logcat message seems to be truncated at the point where it would give me the info on what caused the problem.

Error message:

```
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
    at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseListAdapter.java:127)
    at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter.getItem(FirebaseListAdapter.java:116)
    at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:144)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1670)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
    at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:814)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: com.fasterxml
```

Sometimes it shows an additional period at the end i.e.
`com.fasterxml.`

What can I do to see the whole message? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: try to use the cmd instead of the IDE logcat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how to make the error message appear to appears fully in logcat, but my approach would be to debug the application and enable an exception-breakpoint on `com.firebase.client.FirebaseException`.

In Android Studio open menu *Run* -> *View Breakpoints* -> plus sign -> *3. Java Exception Breakpoints* -> paste `com.firebase.client.FirebaseException` and press OK.

Now if the exception occurs the app will stop and you have the time to view the exception including the full stack trace in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Robert that got me the info I needed!